# TestNG: "No tests were found" when running tests via testng

Tags: selenium, cucumber, testng

I'm trying to run simple Cucumber/Java test, via testng.xml.

So,
I have testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Cucumber Framework">
<test name="Cucumber Tests" junit="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="CucumberFramework.runner.MainRunner"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

And I'm using runner.class in which I'm setting path/options/etc to featurefiles, steps, and reports:

```
package CucumberFramework.runner;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions (
        features = {"src/test/java/CucumberFramework/featureFiles"},
        glue = {"CucumberFramework.steps"},
        monochrome = true,
        tags = {},
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber",
                "json:target/cucumber.json",
                "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/report.html"}
)

public class MainRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

But when I'm running my testng.xml as TestNG suite, it:

1) passing my scenarios themselves,

BUT

2) throwing "No tests were found".
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there is no test methods inside the class a.k.a @Test annotation

Comment: When your runner extend the TestNG class `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests`, then you must not annotate it with JUnit's `@RunWith`. You might also remove the dependency to `cucumber.junit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SubOptimal - thanks man, for so clear explanation, now I know much more.

Regarding trouble itself - finally I resolved it just by deleting junit mentioning in testng.xml. As in description I noted "run as testng suite", I should mark this answer as correct, no offense.

Comment: How do you run your `testng.xml` suite?

Comment: I edited configuration as testng suite, and pressing Run on my testng.xml

Comment: Only to be sure tat we try the same way. Regarding your post it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

A project with Cucumber and TestNG does not require a class with a method annotated with `@Test`.

The `No test were found` might be related to the way you run the Cucumber tests.

Find below a minimal project to show base requirements.

assuming following structure

```
src/test/java/stepdef/StepDefs.java
src/test/java/runner/RunnerTest.java
src/test/resources/features/test.feature
pom.xml
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.suboptimal</groupId>
    <artifactId>cuke-testng3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**test.feature**

```
Feature: test
    Scenario: something to test
        Given some step
        Then this is expected
```

**StepDefs.java**

```
package stepdef;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;

public class StepDefs {
    @Given("^some step$")
    public void someStep() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("execute someStep");
    }

    @Then("^this is expected$")
    public void thisIsExpected() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("execute thisIsExpected");
    }
}
```

**RunnerTest.java**

```
package runner;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features", glue = "stepdef")
public class RunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

The test can be executed via Maven with

```
mvn clean test
```

output

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running runner.RunnerTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@5eb5c224
execute someStep
execute thisIsExpected

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
2 Steps (2 passed)
0m0.019s

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.552 sec
```

As the last line stated `Test run: 1` the Cucumber scenario is recognized as a test run.

**edit** A possibility to execute the Cucumber tests as a TestNG suite.

add to the **pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

create the file **testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Cucumber Framework" >
    <test name="Cucumber Tests">
        <classes>
            <class name="runner.RunnerTest"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

execute the test with Maven as

```
mvn clean test
```

output

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
execute someStep
execute thisIsExpected

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
2 Steps (2 passed)
0m0.020s

[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.614 s - in TestSuite
```

Answer (score 0):

need to add @Test Annotation to make run.

Comment: I don't think that's right. When using a runner which extends `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests` you can run the runner directly `mvn test ...` (either explicit or implicit when its name matches the default pattern). There is no need to run the runner via a TestNG suite. Doing so TestNG will complain that the runner has no `@Test` method. Which is not necessary to be there as the runner class could stay empty.

Comment: yes. sorry Tapan, I should remove green sign. Problem is actual, and Test annotation just did not resolve it. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: That's fine. Thank you @SubOptimal for sharing such informative content.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to share my knowledge and learn from others on SO.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing similar issue when I was storing test data in a spreadsheet.
I added on more column with Execute as Y and this was resolved.